# iOS 12 Fatal Exception: NSInternalInconsistencyException

Tags: ios, swift

I've been receiving many crash report from crashlytics for the past few days. So I check on crashltytics panel and I got

> Fatal Exception: NSInternalInconsistencyException -  the cell returned
>   from -collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath: does not have a
>   reuseIdentifier - cells must be retrieved by calling
>   -dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath:

It is happening only on iOS 12.

I've checked everything and I can't reproduce this bug.

[image: Screenshot from Fabric]

Comment: Please **read** the exception message. It's very descriptive.

Comment: Share your code of this method "cellForItem"

Comment: I have a lot of methods cellForItem. In app are more than 15 collection views.

Comment: Do you do for instance : `guard let customCell = collectionView.dequeue(...) as? CustomCellClass else { return UICollectionViewCell() }`, if that's the case, you might have hit the "else return" (there is not `reuseIndetifier`). Or something like that. You might want to expand also the stacktrace to see if there is a sign of a particular class/viewcontroller. Also, please prefers copy/paste instead of Screenshot, use in Fabrics the "Raw Text".

Comment: Yes, I do. How I expand the stacktrace too see if there is a sign of a particular class?

Comment: Between line "3" and "20", there is a small symbol. But you'll have it all if you tap in "Raw Text" (on the upper right of your screenshot), it's better for a copy/paste.